Nextjs 13.5.1: When another folder is created with app folder, its not showing up on the website
Here, is the thing, I'm creating a dashboard layout website, for that i created a dashboard folder with its layout & page file -> inside the app folder.
That is my current file structure looks like this -> app -> dashboard => layout => page ->layout -> page

Here is the main issue. The web page is only showing the main page & layout content, & not displaying anything from the dashboard folder's content. The consoler is not showing any error related to it, in-fact, the consoler isn't showing the created dashboard folder within the app folder on the source page of consoler. How to fix this?

The issue is not clear.
Is the dashboard content not shown on the "/" route or the "/dashboard" route?
If you want the dashboard content to be shown in "/" route, you should name the dashboard folder as (dashboard).
If not then you should check the naming of the page and layout file and ensure valid functions are exported from them.

First, of all the dashboard folder is named as dashboard only & i have clearly mentioned it, also I have stated the error in a very easy-to-understand way. Secondly, yes, the content of the dashboard page is not showing, & there is no error with the naming.

Browse to "/dashboard" instead of "/"

Hi, I wanted to apologize for my earlier response. After re-reading your reply, I realize I misunderstood your suggestion. Your solution to browse to "/dashboard" indeed works and resolves the issue. I appreciate your help and patience. Thanks again for the clarification!
